# Iterate over the array again or carry an extra variable?

Tags: performance

Say you have an array, and you want to iterate over it, changing each element that is equal to a certain value to 1, and everything else to 0. You will also need to know the number of 1s and 0s in the resulting array, at another point in time.

What's the better way of doing this?

Calculate the number of 1s, as you iterate over the array the first time, and save that number in a variable until you actually need it? Or do sum(array_with_0s_and_1s) later when you need the number of 1s.

Is one way more efficient then the other? Seems to me that doing sum will iterate over the array again and be twice as slow, while counting the number of 1s the first time will just look a bit less elegant, and you'll have to carry an extra variable around.

Comment: Both are equal: Assuming an array with n items, when the equality check and change operation is rated with a cost factor x and the addition operation with a cost factor of y, it doesn’t matter how you do the operation as n·(x+y) = n·x+n·y.

Answer (score 1):

Iteration will be slower that holding a variable, but if the array can change under your feet, it's guaranteed to give the right answer (the variable may be out of date).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small array, the difference should be negligible so do whatever results in better readability/maintainability/otherrandomability for your code.

If iterating over the array a second time causes a noticeable and problematic slowdown, then carry the extra variable around.

9 times out of 10, it won't make a difference, so go for good coding protocol over excessive optimization.